# Corrupt JPG, exceeded buffer limits

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, jpeg

I am trying to add an image (on react native page) using the following code:

```
  <Image
    style={{width: 300}}
    source={require('../../../assets/images/indian-heap-colourful-spices.jpg')}
  />
```

This has caused the following error :

```
 Corrupt JPG, exceeded buffer limits
```

[image]

This is an **image specific** issue,  other images are working fine.

Image file size 1.1 MB
Other image properties are as follows :

[image]

Please help me in understanding what's causing this issue.

Comment: The file is too large to be processed. You may modify the original file or increase the `MaxBufferSize` in server or application settings (perhaps in lib/index.js)

Comment: It may not be the file size as such - if you search for this error, using google, you see some interesting discussions about this exact error - the details of images that work would be good to know ... if it's image specific without being image size specific, try editing the picture in your image editor of choice, and simply save it ... you can also save it with a different quality level to reduce the size of the data - if that helps

Comment: @AliSheikhpour even after reducing the file size to 1.1 MB, I still see the exact same error.